# TCL How to end infinite loop

Tags: tcl

I have tcl(myscript.tcl) script which have `while {1}` loop which is called(executed) via another tcl script(test.tcl). and if myscript.tcl stuck because of while loop then how can terminate using test.tcl after particular time period( e.g 10 seconds)

Comment: When you say it is called via another tcl script, do u mean via `exec` or calling the procedure ?

Comment: Better approach can be performing the validation in the slave itself and return result to master, so that it can be safe to play with.

Comment: Called via another tcl script means via source myscript.tcl

Answer (score 2):

If you run the script `myscript.tcl` within a subordinate interpreter, you can set a time limit on the execution via `interp limit` so that the child interpreter can't go on forever; when the limit is reached, an error is generated which bubbles out to the outer managing interpreter. We explicitly test whether the code that supports limits can break out of infinite loops.

```
set helper [interp create]
# You might need to do some more setup here; do that before setting up the limit
interp limit $helper time -seconds [expr {[clock seconds] + 10}]
catch {interp eval $helper [list source myscript.tcl]}
```